# Asp.Net MVC ModedMetadata question for HiddenInput

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modelmetadata

I have a very simple view-model in a dll that I want to keep separated from the main web mvc project.

I am decorating the model with metadata attributes that will help the ui display the correct presentation (DisplayName, UIHint, DataType, ReadOnly etc) and I would like to reuse this information with different presentation layers later (like Silverlight)

Most of the attributes are coming from the namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
but I was surprised to discover that **HiddenInput** is an exception to that and I need to add a reference to System.Web.Mvc in my view-model dll.

Is there a particular reason not to have included that with the other attributes?

I tried to override the default behavior putting an HiddenInput.ascx in the editortemplates folder but I still get the label for the field when I call an html.EditorfForModel() in my view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason for not being included in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` is because this assembly is part of the BCL and existed before ASP.NET MVC. Brad Wilson wrote a nice [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) covering model metadata in MVC which you might read.

This being said you could use the [`[UIHint]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [UIHint("Hidden")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And in `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Hidden.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x) %>
```

Now you can use `<%= Html.EditorForModel() %>` in your view and it will pick the custom template.

Of course using `[HiddenInput]` is preferred as it makes you write less code but in case you don't want to reference `System.Web.Mvc` in your project you still have the `UIHint` workaround..

Comment: I knw the question is old but I am facing the same issue. I am using [UIHint("Hidden")] but still it displays the label. what am I doing wrong here?